# scp all files within a DIR to remote using ant

Tags: ant, groovy

I was trying to copy all the files within a directory from windows to unix within groovy method using following. But it does give an error saying `No such file or directory`

```
def antMove = new AntBuilder()
antMove.scp(trust: 'true',
            file: "D:\\MyFolder\\input\\*",
            todir: "username@[IP]:/tmp/rw_input/",
            port: "22",
            keyfile: Key,
            passphrase: Passphrase,
            verbose: "true")
```

I tried different option as well like `*.*` and `*` . But no luck

If I give just one file name here like `test.txt` its working fine

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that what You need is `fileset`: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html

Comment: @Opal I had a look there. It gives error `scp doesn't support the "fileset" attribute `. I just replaced `file ` with `fileset ` in the above code

Comment: Hmm.. Will try to reproduce it at spare time.

Comment: Double your backslashes: `file: "D:\\MyFolder\\input\\*"`

Comment: @Steinar I am calling above within a method. So I am passing with double backslashes as you specified. I have put the final path in the question. Updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Fileset can be added in the following way:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.scp(
        todir: "username@[IP]:/tmp/rw_input/",
        verbose: true,
        keyfile: "key",
        trust: true
) {
    fileset(dir: "D:\\MyFolder\\input\\") {
        include(name: '*')
    }
}
```